# make cube fall?

Tags: rigidbody

Simple question, all I want to do is make a cube fall onto a plan in blender game using physics engine. I used to be able to do this but jutt can't get it to work and want to start toying around with it.

Answer (score 2):

- After you put a plane and a cube above it you should add first of all a rigidbody to the cube
- In order to add a **Rigidbody** to your **Cube** you have to move to **Physics table** inside the right menu

[image]
 - This will allow your cube to fall down.

- After this you have to select your **Plane** and add a **Rigidbody**
  to it in order to make it "solid" and collidable with your cube, so you have to move to "**Rigidbody**" menu and then select "**Passive**" to it so it won't fall down for gravity, remember that your cube is "**Active**", like this:

[image]

- I'm not really expert in these kind of things, just starting with Blender, I hope this is the correct way and I hope that maybe this will help you, also I hope that this was corcerning the thing that you were asking about

Comment: My blender looks nothing like this, https://imgur.com/a/mMel556

Comment: @ketchupboy2002 Yes sorry, I was using Blender 2.8 the new version, by the way, I added the correct screenshoot for your version, check them now, this steps will allow your cube to fall down and the plane to not fall

Answer (score 0):

After adding the rigid body through the physics menu, you can active it through this menu,https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaMIL.jpg